# Matrix Representation $[T]_\beta^\alpha$ of $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: linear-algebra, solution-verification

We have the transformation $T:\mathbb{R}^3 \to P_2(\mathbb{R})$ defined by $T(a_1, a_2, a_3) = (a_1 + a_2 + a_3) + (a_1 - a_2 + a_3)x + a_1x^2$.

We know the standard ordered basis of the domain $\mathbb{R}^3$ is $\beta =  ${ (1,0,0), (0,1,0), (0,0,1) }$.

We know the standard ordered basis of the image $P_2(\mathbb{R})$ is $\alpha = \{1, x, x^2\}$.

Applying $T$ to each element of $\beta$ we get:

- $T((1,0,0)) = 1+x+x^2$

  $T((0,1,0)) = 1-x$

  $T((0,0,1)) = 1+x$

Now, my question is how do I use these to create the matrix representation $[T]_\beta^\alpha$?

Do I just express each thing in terms of the image's basis $\alpha$?

If I do that, I would get:

- $T((1,0,0))^\alpha = (1, 1, 1)$

  $T((0,1,0))^\alpha = (1, -1, 0)$

  $T((0,0,1))^\alpha = (1, 1,0)$

This would give me:

- $[T]_\beta^\alpha = \begin{pmatrix} 1&1&1\\ 1&-1&1 \\ 1&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$

Does this look right?

THANK YOU!

Comment: Yeah, it looks good. One small thing, it looks like you're missing a $1$ in the first column of the matrix.

Comment: Now it is okay, good job!

Comment: In the future you'd like to be able to know how to verify this. The way to do it is multiplying the matrix by your basis vectors and see that you get the vector you're supposed to.